std::unique_ptr<DBusMessage> != nullptr after move into function parameter
I'm trying to write a program that uses DBus to interact with BlueZ. From the information I have been able to gather from the DBus docs, BlueZ DBus API docs, and various forums, my thought process was as follows:

Connect to DBus
Start discovery using the "default" adapter (just hard-coded to hci0)
Use org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.GetManagedObjects() to find available devices.

So I have wrote the following code:
#include <...>
#include <dbus-1.0/dbus/dbus.h>

struct DBusDeleter
{
    void operator()(DBusConnection *connection) {dbus_connection_unref(connection);}
    void operator()(DBusMessage *msg) {dbus_message_unref(msg);}
    void operator()(DBusError *err) {dbus_error_free(err);}
};

void print_managed_objects(std::unique_ptr<DBusMessage, DBusDeleter> message)
{
    DBusMessageIter message_iter;
    dbus_message_iter_init(message.get(), &message_iter);
    std::cout << (char) dbus_message_iter_get_arg_type(&message_iter) << '\n';

    DBusMessageIter dict_iter;
    dbus_message_iter_recurse(&message_iter, &dict_iter);
    std::cout << (char) dbus_message_iter_get_arg_type(&dict_iter) << '\n';

    while(dbus_message_iter_get_arg_type(&dict_iter) == DBUS_TYPE_DICT_ENTRY)
    {
        DBusMessageIter entry_iter;
        dbus_message_iter_recurse(&dict_iter, &entry_iter);

        char * object_path;

        dbus_message_iter_get_basic(&entry_iter, object_path);
        std::cout << object_path << "\n";

        std::cout << (char) dbus_message_iter_get_arg_type(&entry_iter) << '\n';

        dbus_message_iter_next(&dict_iter);
    }
    std::cout << std::flush;
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<DBusError, DBusDeleter> dbus_error(new DBusError);
    dbus_error_init(dbus_error.get());

    std::shared_ptr<DBusConnection> conn(dbus_bus_get(DBUS_BUS_SYSTEM, dbus_error.get()), DBusDeleter());

    if (dbus_error_is_set(dbus_error.get()))
    {
        std::cout << "DBus Error: " << dbus_error->message << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::string service_name = "org.bluez";
    std::unique_ptr<DBusMessage, DBusDeleter> msg, reply;

    // Start Device Discovery

    msg.reset(dbus_message_new_method_call(service_name.c_str(), "/org/bluez/hci0", "org.bluez.Adapter1", "StartDiscovery"));
    reply.reset(nullptr);

    uint32_t serial = 1;

    dbus_connection_send(conn.get(), msg.get(), &serial);

    if (dbus_error_is_set(dbus_error.get()))
    {
        std::cout << "BlueZ Error (Failed to start discovery): " << dbus_error->message << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::chrono::duration<int64_t> scan_duration = std::chrono::seconds(10);
    std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::time_point start_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    msg.reset(dbus_message_new_method_call(service_name.c_str(), "/", "org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager", "GetManagedObjects"));

    while (start_time + scan_duration >= std::chrono::system_clock::now())
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));

        reply = std::unique_ptr<DBusMessage, DBusDeleter>(dbus_connection_send_with_reply_and_block(conn.get(), msg.get(), -1, dbus_error.get()));

        if (dbus_error_is_set(dbus_error.get()))
        {
            std::cout << "error with reply: " << dbus_error->message << "\n";
            break;
        }

        print_managed_objects(std::move(reply));
        
        if (reply == nullptr) {
            std::cout << "All Good!\n";
            continue;
        }

        std::cout << "Something went wrong!\n";
        break;
    }

    // more code...
}

The issue happens right around the print_managed_objects function call. When the function returns, I would expect that since the print_managed_objects function has already consumed the message as I had gave it ownership of the message, that everything would be okay, but the check for nullptr fails on the original unique_ptr that was moved from.
This means that the reply pointer still has a reference to the message which was destroyed after print_managed_objects returned, and when resetting the pointer in the next iteration of the loop, the program would crash because DBus would spit out this error:

dbus[15920]: arguments to dbus_message_unref() were incorrect, assertion "message->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file dbus-message.c line 1728

My question is why is reply's internal pointer not set to nullptr after the move? According to another Stack Overflow question, calling std::move() on a unique pointer will set that pointer's internal pointer to nullptr.
Edit: I had left out lines in the print_managed_objects function that I thought I could leave out for a minimal reproducible example, but those lines were actually necessary for the error to occur. Specifically, these lines:
char * object_path;

dbus_message_iter_get_basic(&entry_iter, object_path);
std::cout << *object_path << "\n";


Just remember it, std::move() does not move an object content. Please show print_managed_objects() definition. which is another function I wrote, but is irrelevant - the function is most relevant here.

Is the definition really necessary? It just iterates through the response sent from BlueZ and that's it. it doesn't do anything else with the pointer except iterating through the array of managed objects and prints out object paths. I probably should've mentioned that the while loop runs successfully on the first iteration.

Instead of describing the code, you should post a [mcve].

ok. I posted the function in the code snippet.

That seems like a lot more code than necessary.  I'd expect it to be more minimal.

It looks like a correct code, maybe is not what you actually run.

Yes, I had originally left some lines out of the print_managed_objects function for the minimal reproducible example, without checking to make sure the error still happened with the code I actually did post. :(

@SwampyX I see nothing in this code that would cause the symptom you describe. This is hardly a [mcve] (emphasis on reproducible). But in any case, constructing a unique_ptr from a moved unique_ptr guarantees the latter gets reset to nullptr, so what you claim can't be what's really happening.

Here is an issue.
char * object_path;
dbus_message_iter_get_basic(&entry_iter, object_path);
std::cout << *object_path << "\n";

You pass the uninitialized pointer to the function. This is undefined behavior. You seem to get corrupted stack data in your case.
std::cout << *object_path << "\n";

I don't know what you expect there. As for the 3rd line, you likely expect a single char data. The code should be
char object_path;
dbus_message_iter_get_basic(&entry_iter, &object_path);
std::cout << object_path << "\n";

&object_path passes the address of the char storage.
The top code is showing
std::cout << object_path << "\n"

So, I am confused by your code.
A similar example is shown in the manual. You could easy follow it instead of trials.
dbus_message_iter_get_basic().

I was trying to get a string value, so object_path would still be a char *, but it seems I forgot the address operator when sending it to dbus_message_iter_get_basic, and what I think actually happened was that I was printing out memory addresses where the actual strings were located. still dont understand why that would cause reply to not be null. Any ideas?

Looks like a stack memory corruption. "Why" is a wrong question when you get undefined behavior.
